# How to change object's properties' places?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have an object playerInfoObject with properties w1 and w2, which are also objects.

I need to change their places between each other

They become equal when I'm trying to do this:

```
    var tmp = playerInfoObject.w1;
    playerInfoObject.w1 = playerInfoObject.w2;
    playerInfoObject.w2 = tmp;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) helps you? Unless i did not understand your question

Comment: How do you define your variable `playerInfoObject`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kkgy0co6/1/ ?

Comment: @Burki, I just need to set the key w2 to w1 and w1 to w2

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: @weratius your code is working just fine.... can you recreate the issue

Comment: Please print out `playerInfoObject` before and after your swap.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use EcmaScript 6, a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables) can solve it without a temporary variable:

```
playerInfoObject = {
  w1: {w: '1'},
  w2: {w: '2'}
};

[playerInfoObject.w1, playerInfoObject.w2] = [playerInfoObject.w2, playerInfoObject.w1];
```

Or with [object destructuring](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html#you_can_assign_to_more_than_just_variables) directly:

```
({w1: playerInfoObject.w2, w2: playerInfoObject.w1}) = playerInfoObject;
```

Otherwise, your code seems to be working fine.

Comment: thank you, but I can't use that. Couldn't you check that out http://jsfiddle.net/Costa595/62zxdoqz/, that still doesn't help

Comment: It doesn't work, partially because you haven't defined `playerInfoObject`.

Comment: ...and because you hadn't loaded jQuery in your fiddle. Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/62zxdoqz/1/

Comment: I meant that it doesn't work properly in my project, in jsfiddle I just wanted to show the code and that's all

Comment: I'm still not understand *what* isn't working... can you provide a full example I can test where it doesn't work the way you expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

`=` operator places a reference between the object, you need to clone it.

```
var tmp = JSON.decode(JSON.encode(playerInfoObject.w1));
playerInfoObject.w1 = JSON.decode(JSON.encode(playerInfoObject.w2));
playerInfoObject.w2 = tmp;
```

You can find more elegant ways of cloning objects but this should work.